# UIImageView in custom UIITableViewCell not toggling on reload

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell. I've got a `UIImageView` on top of a `UIButton`. Now when I click the `UIButton`, I'm able to toggle the image of the `UIImageView` something similar to a radio button.

The problem is, when I toggle it to the state 'YES', there is a call to the server that makes the required change. Now when I reload the table, the `UIImageView` doesnt change to the 'YES' state. I set the `UIButton` state to 'Selected' and that's working fine. But the `UIImageView` doesnt change to the new image.

On update I get this:
[image]

When I actually want this: [image]

The default state is this: [image]

The updated state and the default state of the `UIImageView` is the same.

Here the round icon is the `UIImageView` and the rest is a `UIButton`

This is what I've been trying to do:

In the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.karmaLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.karmaButton.frame.size.width - 40, 8, 30, 30)];
    [self.karmaLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-grey"]];
    self.karmaLogo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.karmaButton addSubview:self.karmaLogo];
}
```

And in the `UITableView` delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Creates the required custom cell
    if (karmaCheck == 1) // Received from the server
    {
        cell.karmaButton.highlighted = YES;
        cell.karmaButton.selected = YES;
        cell.karmaLogo.image = nil;
        [cell.karmaLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-black"]];
        [cell.karmaLogo setNeedsDisplay];
        [cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.karmaLogo];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.karmaButton.highlighted = NO;
        cell.karmaButton.selected = NO;
        cell.karmaLogo.image = nil;
        [cell.karmaLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-grey"]];
        [cell.karmaLogo setNeedsDisplay];
        [cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.karmaLogo];
    }
```

The execution does enter both the if and the else block as and when required but doesnt change the image. But the highlighting and the selection of the karmaButton (`UIButton`) works fine.

Comment: try setting the image to nothing, then setting the image to black

Comment: Doesnt cell.karmaLogo.image = nil; have the same effect?

Comment: In theory yes, but try `[cell.karmaLogo setImage:nil]];` instead and see what happens

Comment: Nope. That doesnt help

Comment: how are you building the custom cell? From a XIB or code? Also, for debugging instead of adding the UIImageView to UIButton, try adding it directly to the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you statement "when I reload the table, the UIImageView doesnt change to the 'YES' state."

This is because whenever you reload the Table your `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` gets called in which you are explicitly setting the image in `ImageView` using `[self.karmaLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-grey"]];`

So do your conditional checking in `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the image as a subview of the button, so the image is getting highlighted when you highlight the button. The reason you're seeing a problem, I think, is due to a bug in `UIImageView` when you don't explicitly set the highlighted image. So, rather than toggling the image, try doing this outside of your `if-else` block:

```
[cell.karmaLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-grey"]];
[cell.karmaLogo setHighlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-black"]];
```